# Building Python C++ extension fails on overloaded functions

Tags: c++

I want to write a Python module in C++ and try to biuld it with `distutils`, but it suddenly gave me a compilation error when I tried to use overloaded functions. How can I cope with them?

Here is a simple module, written according to [official manual.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html)

The module consists of 3 files: `pymega.cpp` (module interfaces for Python interpreter), `payload.h` and `payload.cpp` (here should be the "payload").

**pymega.cpp**

```
//pymega.cpp
#include <Python.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "payload.h"

static PyObject* test(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  cout << "Running test method!" << endl;
  cout << "^__^" << endl;

  PyMega::uber_function(7, 40);
  return Py_None;
}

//Module methods declatarion
static PyMethodDef Methods[] = {
    {"test",  test, METH_VARARGS, "Hell yeah!!"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef pymega = {
   PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
   "pymega",   /* name of module */
   NULL, /* module documentation, may be NULL */
   -1,       /* size of per-interpreter state of the module,
                or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
   Methods
};

// Module nitialization
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_pymega(void)
{
  cout << "Initializing PyMega..." << endl;
  PyObject *m;

  m = PyModule_Create(&pymega);
  if (m == NULL)
  {
    cout << "PyMega init failed" << endl;
    return NULL;
  }

  return m;
}
```

**payload.h**

```
//payload.h
#ifndef PAYLOAD_H_
#define PAYLOAD_H_

#include <Python.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace PyMega {

  void uber_function(unsigned int arg1);
  void uber_function(unsigned int arg1, unsigned int arg2);

} // PyMega


#endif  // PAYLOAD_H_
```

**payload.cpp**

```
//payload.cpp
#include "payload.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

using namespace PyMega;

void uber_function(unsigned int arg1)
{
  cout << "uber_function " << arg1 << endl;
}

void uber_function(unsigned int arg1, unsigned int arg2)
{
  cout << "uber_function " << arg1 << " " << arg2 << endl;
  uber_function(arg1);
}
```

Also, here is `setup.py` (my setup script).

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('pymega',
                    sources=['pymega.cpp', "payload.cpp"],
                    language="c++")

setup (name='PackageName',
       version='1.0',
       description='This is a demo package',
       ext_modules=[module1])
```

When I try to run `setup.py build`, it gives me the following error log:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'pymega' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes 
-g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security 
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c pymega.cpp -o build/temp.
linux-x86_64-3.4/pymega.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC 
but not for C++ [enabled by default]
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes 
-g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security 
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c payload.cpp -o build/temp
.linux-x86_64-3.4/payload.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC 
but not for C++ [enabled by default]
payload.cpp: In function ‘void uber_function(unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
payload.cpp:16:21: error: call of overloaded ‘uber_function(unsigned int&)’ is a
mbiguous
   uber_function(arg1);
                     ^
payload.cpp:16:21: note: candidates are:
payload.cpp:8:6: note: void uber_function(unsigned int)
 void uber_function(unsigned int arg1)
      ^
In file included from payload.cpp:1:0:
payload.h:11:8: note: void PyMega::uber_function(unsigned int)
   void uber_function(unsigned int arg1);
        ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Is any of the Python stuff actually necessary to reproduce the problem? Does it need multiple files? Please create a minimal example. That said, `1` is of type `int`, while the functions want `unsigned int`. It's possible that you need `1u` instead, but I'm to lazy to analyze all your code before you minimized it.

Comment: Yes, it does need 3 files to reproduce the error. When I tried to merge it in 1 file, the error disappeared. But of course, there are much more functions and the functions are much longer.

Comment: `#include` will just paste the file content in-place, so I can't believe you made a proper effort to reproduce a minimala example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `void uber_function(int)` in the `::PyMega` namespace, and then went on to define `void uber_function(int)` in the `::` namespace. These are two different functions from different namespaces with the same names and signatures, which results in a conflict. Probably not what you intended.

To define `::PyMega::uber_function` you **must** say

```
namespace PyMega
{
   void uber_function(int) {
       ....
   }
}
```